# Modifying field names in Lucene Query

Tags: lucene

I am looking for a way to modify the field names of a Lucene [Query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html), using a known mapping from field name to encoded field name.

For example, if I have a query *title:System* , I would need it transformed into the query *a200:System* (I know the mapping from field encoding mapping title->a200)

I could write a function to transform a query, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do this.
The function would be something like:
public Query rewriteWithEncodedFields(Query query, Map encodings) { ... }

If there is an option for this in one of the QueryParsers, that would be great too, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Solr provides this sort of functionality, but Lucene itself doesn't, to the best of my knowledge.

You can transform the query string, as you indicated, or you can create a custom query parser.

Poking around, the implementation I've seen is to, if you are using the standard [`QueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html) as a base, override:

- `getFieldQuery`
- `getFuzzyQuery`
- `getPrefixQuery`
- `getRangeQuery`
- `getRegexpQuery`
- `getWildcardQuery`

Something like:

```java
public class CustomQueryParser extends QueryParser {
    protected Query getFieldQuery(String field, String queryText, int slop) {
          return super.getFieldQuery(replaceAlias(field), queryText, slop);
    }

    protected Query getFuzzyQuery(String field, String termStr, float minSimilarity) throws ParseException {
          return super.getFuzzyQuery(replaceAlias(field), termStr, minSimilarity);
    }

    //etc.

    private String replaceAlias(String field) {
          //transform as appropriate...
    }
}
```